# NUnit and Task Parallel Library conflicts on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, nunit-3.0

I'm experiencing an odd crash when combining NUnit and the TPL on Mono. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Engine;

namespace BadMono
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mono is bad.");
            DryRun();
        }

        private static void DryRun()
        {
            // Code based on:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826500/how-to-run-a-nunit-test

            string path = @"<snip>/bin/Debug/TestChannelA.dll";

            TestPackage package = new TestPackage(path);
            package.AddSetting("WorkDirectory", Environment.CurrentDirectory);

            // prepare the engine
            ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();

            // ERROR happens on this line
            var _filterService = engine.Services.GetService<ITestFilterService>();
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the following NuGet packages:

```
NUnit.Engine v3.2.0
NUnit v3.2.0
Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow v4.5.24
```

So if I run this code on Windows 10 (.NET 4.6.1), the program prints "Mono is bad." without crashing.

I am compiling in Visual Studio 2015 and then testing on Linux using mono. If I run this on Linux (OpenSUSE 13.2), I get this stack trace:

```
BadMono/bin/Debug $ mono BadMono.exe
Mono is bad.

Unhandled Exception:
Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
  at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) <0x41f5df10 + 0x00333> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name) <0x41f5dec0 + 0x0003e> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name) <0x41f5d890 + 0x00073> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) <0x41f5d530 + 0x000f3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) <0x41f5d2a0 + 0x0002a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve () <0x41f5d240 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Internal.CecilExtensions.GetAttribute (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type, System.String fullName) <0x41f5a300 + 0x000b6> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Services.ExtensionService.FindExtensionsInAssembly (System.String assemblyName, Boolean specifiedInConfig) <0x41f46f80 + 0x0032f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Services.ExtensionService.FindExtensionsInDirectory (System.IO.DirectoryInfo startDir) <0x41f46b10 + 0x00177> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Services.ExtensionService.StartService () <0x41f45640 + 0x000ab> in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
  at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) <0x41f5df10 + 0x00333> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name) <0x41f5dec0 + 0x0003e> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name) <0x41f5d890 + 0x00073> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) <0x41f5d530 + 0x000f3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) <0x41f5d2a0 + 0x0002a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve () <0x41f5d240 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Internal.CecilExtensions.GetAttribute (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type, System.String fullName) <0x41f5a300 + 0x000b6> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Services.ExtensionService.FindExtensionsInAssembly (System.String assemblyName, Boolean specifiedInConfig) <0x41f46f80 + 0x0032f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Services.ExtensionService.FindExtensionsInDirectory (System.IO.DirectoryInfo startDir) <0x41f46b10 + 0x00177> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Services.ExtensionService.StartService () <0x41f45640 + 0x000ab> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Here is the version of Mono I am using:

```
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.0 (Stable 4.4.0.40/f8474c4 Wed Mar 30 18:05:27 PDT 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

**Odd Fix #1**
If I comment out the following line, the program works fine on Linux/mono:

```
private static void DryRun()
{
    ... // other code the same

    // If I comment out this SINGLE LINE, the program works fine.
    // var _filterService = engine.Services.GetService<ITestFilterService>();
}
```

**Odd Fix #2**

Let's say now that I leave the code as it originally was (with the `_filterService` line not commented). If I remove a single .dll file in the working directory, I don't get the crash. Let me show you the original files:

```
<snip>BadMono/bin/Debug $ ls
 .
 ..
 BadMono.exe
 BadMono.exe.config
 BadMono.pdb
 BadMono.vshost.exe
 BadMono.vshost.exe.config
 Mono.Cecil.dll
 System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll
 System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.xml
 nunit-agent-x86.exe
 nunit-agent.exe
 nunit.engine.api.dll
 nunit.engine.dll
 nunit.framework.dll
 nunit.framework.xml
```

Now If I remove `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll`, the program works fine again. Windows doesn't exhibit this problem and works fine in any circumstance I describe; it's only mono / Linux that has the issue.

This is really odd to me because I'm not even actually calling any of the Tasks.Dataflow (TPL) stuff in this example code. Can someone shed light on what's going on here, please?

Comment: Do you have the `mono-devel` package installed?

Comment: @svick Yes, but it is version 3.0.6-3.1.3, which is for openSUSE 13.1. I compiled mono 4.4.0 from source and set the prefix install to a user path. I put this path in the PATH environment variable so that the version I built from source would be found before the version for openSUSE.