# NUnit Engine in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, nunit, nunit-3.0

Good Afternoon,

For my current project I'm trying to create a NUnit Runner that will be hosted in our Development Server.
For a quick version, I'm using ASP.NET Webforms + latest version of NUnit from NuGet (currently 3.4.1, both Engine + Core). I'm following the suggestions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826500/how-to-run-a-nunit-test) on how to run a test from code.

When loading my application I'm getting the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
Source Error: 
Line 33:             {
Line 34:                 // execute the tests            
Line 35:                 XmlNode result = runner.Run(null, emptyFilter);
Line 36:                 lblTest.Text = result.InnerText;
Line 37:             }
```

My NUnit library is located in the Binary folder from the Web Application, so I don't know why is unable to locate 'nunit.framework' from there.

This is the actual code that I'm using for the runner:

```
using NUnit.Engine;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;

namespace NunitWebRunner
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // set up the options
            string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            TestPackage package = new TestPackage(path);
            package.AddSetting("WorkDirectory", Environment.CurrentDirectory);

            // prepare the engine
            ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();
            var _filterService = engine.Services.GetService<ITestFilterService>();
            ITestFilterBuilder builder = _filterService.GetTestFilterBuilder();
            TestFilter emptyFilter = builder.GetFilter();

            using (ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package))
            {
                // execute the tests            
                XmlNode result = runner.Run(null, emptyFilter);
                lblTest.Text = result.InnerText;
            }
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TemplateTestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestThatPasses()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestThatFails()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(4, 5);
        }

        [Test]
        [Ignore("Ignored")]
        public void IgnoredeTest()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea of what is happening, or how I can try to fix it to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion in [Nunit-Dicussion Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/5p4P7JYUJxU) the solution to this problem was really easy.

Charlie commented above, the issue is with the current configurations that are used in the code. instead of using "WorkingDirectory", "ProcessModel" and "DomainUsage" should be setted so NUnit runner can be executed without problems in a Web environment like ASP.NET.

Below you can find the code that mark this thread as aswered.

```
using NUnit.Engine;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;

namespace NunitWebRunner
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // set up the options
            string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            TestPackage package = new TestPackage(path);
            package.AddSetting("ProcessModel", "Single");
            package.AddSetting("DomainUsage", "None");

            // prepare the engine
            ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();
            var _filterService = engine.Services.GetService<ITestFilterService>();
            ITestFilterBuilder builder = _filterService.GetTestFilterBuilder();
            TestFilter emptyFilter = builder.GetFilter();

            using (ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package))
            {
                // execute the tests            
                XmlNode result = runner.Run(null, emptyFilter);
                lblTest.Text = result.InnerText;
            }
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TemplateTestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestThatPasses()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestThatFails()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(4, 5);
        }

        [Test]
        [Ignore("Ignored")]
        public void IgnoredeTest()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeating my answer from the nunit-discuss list, where the question was posted at about the same time as here. @Glenn Rodriguez such multi-posting is considered rude in many circles. It forces those of us who answer to do double work so that folks who see the question will also be able to find the answer.

---

"As a first question... are you trying to create a runner or do you
simply want a self-executing test? Your example is a self-executing
test, but perhaps you were just doing that for the sake of an example.
If all you want is a self-executing test, then we have NUnitLite that
does precisely what your example shows.

"OTOH, if you are creating your own runner, you should use the engine
as you are doing. (The second approach in the SO question you linked
is wrong - it will work in simple cases but will run into problems
eventually because that's not what the console runner is designed
for.)

"Your code can be simpler wrt the filter. Just use TestFilter.Empty
when running all tests.

"Your TestPackage is using all default settings except for
WorkDirectory. That means NUnit will try to run your tests by creating
a separate process and launching it using the NUnit test agent. This
is probably not what you want. Use a "ProcessModel" setting of
"Single" to run tests in the current process. You may also need a
"DomainUsage" setting of "None" if you don't want NUnit to create a
separate domain for the test. Try it both ways.

"Good luck!"

---

I'll add a few further comments...

The first method suggested in the SO post you linked has the right idea but is incomplete as it relies entirely on the engine's default settings.

The second method suggested appears to work until you try to run more than once in the same program. The console runner Main is not intended to be called as anything except a Main.

When asking a question about something out of the ordinary that you are doing, it usually helps people to help you if you can explain why you are doing it.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was rude, I just was looking for more aswers for my situation, I guess it get out of hand.
I didn't know a discussion group exists, and I created my post there after I created my post here.

Regarding why I'm doing this, well... We are using a third party software and extending it with the API they provided. I created some REST services, but sometimes we deployed a change sometimes the service broke and we didn't notice until is used and we need to wait a new deployment cycle from our third party vendor.

Comment: We are planning to use this Web Runner as a Integration Testing / Health Check for our services (more in the like as JUnitEE but for .NET).
I will mark this post as resolved when I get the chance to test the recomendations from the group, when I get something I will update the asnwer here and close this post.